# Generic type where T can be anything

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write one generic c# method which will be look like this:

```
MyClass.Function1<string>()
MyClass.Function1<IEnumerable<string>>()
MyClass.Function1<IDictionary<string, string>>()
MyClass.Function1<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>()
```

T can be anything

```
T = string
T = IEnumerable<string>
T = IDictionary<string, string>
T = IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
```

Second question

Can I create one static method will be not depends on type?

```
string GetSth().Function1();
IEnumerable<string> GetSth().Function1()
IDictionary<string, string> GetSth().Function1()
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> GetSth().Function1()
```

Comment: What will `Function1` do with the type argument?

Comment: Sounds like you need to just read an intro tutorial on generics, and ask a question after you run into a more specific problem trying to implement your method.  Yes, it can potentially allow you to do both of those things, but it will depend on how specifically you want to do them, and what the method actually needs to do.

Comment: Ask **one** question per question, not two.

Comment: yes. this is the generic method. `public void Function1<T>(){}` which accepts anything.

Comment: What do you want to do inside Function1?

Comment: probably say hi to the generic type `T` :D @Shadmehr

Comment: In my honest opinion there´s not mcuh you can do with *every possible* datatype unless printing its string-representation and asking for its type which is both already implemented on `object`. So what do you want to do for all those types? Your question is quite unclear and will thus soon be closed.

Comment: I can´t even see anything that you can do with `string` `IEnumerable<string>`, `IDictionary<string, string>` and `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`, not to mention all the other types like `int`, `bool`, `object`, `IAnyInterface`.

Comment: The generic T could be a generic also. So...

Comment: @HimBromBeere Look at every LINQ method; look at any collection, etc.  There are lots of sensible implementations of operations that can act on *any* type.  I agree the question is unclear, but not because there aren't any sensible things to do in a method that can act on any type, but rather because there are so many possible things one might want to do in such an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For First question define a generic class with where to shared interface such as IEnumerable or without any where clause :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string Function1<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).FullName;
    }
    public static string Function2<T>() where T : IEnumerable
    {
        return typeof(T).FullName;
    }
}
```

And For second one define an [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) :

```
public static class MyClass_Extensions
{
    public static string StaticMethod1(this object obj)
    {
        return obj?.ToString();
    }

    public static string StaticMethod2(this IEnumerable obj)
    {
        return obj?.ToString();
    }
}
```

So we can write this test method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function1<string>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function1<IEnumerable<string>>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function1<IDictionary<string, string>>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function1<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>());

        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function2<string>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function2<IEnumerable<string>>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function2<IDictionary<string, string>>());
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Function2<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>());

        // Static Method:
        var strObj = "string";
        Console.WriteLine(strObj.StaticMethod1());
        Console.WriteLine(strObj.StaticMethod2());

        IEnumerable<string> listObj = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(listObj.StaticMethod1());
        Console.WriteLine(listObj.StaticMethod2());

        IDictionary<string, string> dicObj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Console.WriteLine(dicObj.StaticMethod1());
        Console.WriteLine(dicObj.StaticMethod2());

        IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> dicLisObj = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
        Console.WriteLine(dicLisObj.StaticMethod1());
        Console.WriteLine(dicLisObj.StaticMethod2());
    }
}
```